# Terraform init does NOT download .git directory to .terraform/modules when multiple calls to the same module are made

Tags: git, terraform

I am working on a project where I need to run some git bash commands within a module to generate a tag identifier with the name and tag of the current module and any of its nested modules. This will be used to ensure people are using our approved modules as well as making sure they are in complaince with the version.
IF I have a terraform deployment that instantiates multiple instances of the same module and I run terraform init, it all downloads them to their corresponding module path directories within .terraform/modules. However, I noticed that the first instance directory indeed contains it's .git directory but any subdequent instances of that same module do NOT have the .git directory in it. WHen I run my git commands against the first instance I can reliably get the basename and tag of that module...however when I run it against the second instance, since the .git directory does not exist in there, it looks like it works its way up the directory hierarchy until it finds the .git directory in the root of the module itself. THis in effect is returning the wrong modulename and tag since it is the nested module name and tag I am looking for

Is this by design that the .git directories are NOT downloaded to each instance folder in the .terraform/modules directory?